# HttpClient is not working with localhost

Tags: java, web-services, localhost, apache-commons-httpclient

I developed a web service in java Jersey REST. I used HttpClient to call a a basic GET method.

When using this URL `http://localhost:8080/myserver/rest/location` on browser, it works.

When using this code to call the GET method, I get a 404 Not Found error.

```
private static final String BASIC_URL = "http://localhost:8080/myserver/rest/location";

public static boolean isAlive() throws URISyntaxException, ClientProtocolException, IOException{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get=new HttpGet(BASIC_URL);
    System.out.println(get.getURI());

      System.out.println("after adding all namevalues: "+get.getURI());
      HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get);
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

    if (statusLine.getStatusCode() != 200) {
        System.out.println("response status="+statusLine.getStatusCode());
        return false;
    }
    System.out.println("Response sent succesfully with status "+200);
    return true;
}
```

Any clue?

UPDATE

Also, I tried `http://192.168.9.160:8080/LocationRetreiverServer/rest/location` (my local IP) and it gave Not Found error !!

Comment: What does it show on the browser?

Comment: It shows 200 OK response with a string displayed.

Comment: Does your jersey REST service have any logic that might return a 404?

Comment: No. Responses are OK or NOT_ACCEPTABLE. And both are not 404.

Answer (score 0):

The response "404 Not Found" clearly indicates that you successfully made an HTTP request to the server, which returned this HTTP response. So the trouble doesn't seem to originate with the localhost part.

You may be missing some required headers, for example.

Compare the full HTTP request as issued by the browser and as issued by your HttpClient.

Comment: How to track the request issued by the browser? From the server side?

Comment: If you can log it at the server side, that would be great. Otherwise there's always WireShark.

Comment: Thanks. For others who might need a faster way, I used Chrome Network developer tool.

Comment: But you should also see the detailed request from your Java code, if you want to be sure what exactly is sent to the server.